# Converting SQL subquery to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

I am new to LINQ and trying to convert an SQL subquery to lINQ. Can we write subqueries like SQL in LINQ?

here is the database

```
Table EMP                                                                                                  
Name       Null?         Type

EMPNO      NOT NULL      NUMBER(4)
NAME                    VARCHAR2(10)
JOB                     VARCHAR2(9)
MGR                     NUMBER(4)
HIREDATE                DATE
SAL                     NUMBER(7,2)
COMM                    NUMBER(7,2)
DEPTNO                  NUMBER(2)


Table Dpt
Name        Null?        Type
DEPTNO      NOT NULL NUMBER(2)
DNAME                VARCHAR2(14)
LOC                  VARCHAR2(13)
```

Here is the SQL query

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE deptno IN (SELECT deptno
                 FROM dept
                 WHERE dname = 'RESEARCH');
```

Here is my effort:

```
var r = (from query in conn.EMPs
         where (query.DEPTNO == (from q in conn.DEPTs 
                                 where q.DNAME == "RESERCH"
                                 select q.DEPTNO)) 
         select new
         {
          query
         }).ToList();
```

Comment: What's wrong with your effort? Why not use join?

Comment: You might want to checkout _Linqpad_

Comment: I had done this using joins but I am wondering can we do this using subqueries. if yes, then what's the right format because I am getting wrong syntax error while executing this.

Comment: `where ((from q in conn.DEPTs 
                                 where q.DNAME == "RESERCH"
                                 select q.DEPTNO).Contains(query.DEPTNO))`

Comment: still not working here is the new error

Error 1 'System.Linq.IQueryable<byte>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\Slahu\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication10\WebApplication10\Controllers\DefaultController.cs 20 64 WebApplication10

Comment: `from emp in conn.EMPs
                    where conn.DEPTs.Where(d=>d.DNAME == "RESERCH").Select(d=>d.DEPTNO).Contains(emp.deptno)
                    select new ...`

Comment: change this part: `select new
         {
           f1 = query,
         }`

Comment: Off topic: don't abbreviations property and class names. On-topic, make sure `Employee` has a navigation property `Department` after which this becomes ridiculously easy.

Comment: still getting same errors ::
    1)      'System.Linq.IQueryable<byte>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments 


                2) Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<byte>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<byte?>'

Comment: Please show the `EMP` and `DEPT` classes (or Employee and Department after giving them proper names). You're  making this way too hard.

Comment: EMP........................


 EMPNO...                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(4)...
 ENAME...                                              VARCHAR2(10)...
 JOB         ...                                       VARCHAR2(9)...
 MGR           ...                                     NUMBER(4)...
 COMM           ...                                    NUMBER(7,2)...
 DEPTNO          ...                                   NUMBER(2)...

Comment: Please edit your question. And I mean the *classes* not the database tables.

Comment: You may find my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I like using joins :

```
var r = (from query in conn.EMPs
        join q in conn.DEPTs on query.deptno equals q.DEPTNO 
        select new { query = query, q = q})
        .Where(x => x.q.DNAME == "RESEARCH")
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

var departmentNos = dept.Where(dpt => dpt.dname == 'RESEARCH').Select(dptNo => 
                    dptNo.deptno);

var employees = emp.Where(e => departmentNos.Contains(e.deptno));

employees is the final outcome.